# Двухфакторная авторизация на Laravel 5

Tags: laravel, laravel5, аутентификация, 2fa

Разрабатываю проект (на Laravel 5.4), на котором будет действовать публичная оферта. У руководства появились вопросы по поводу безопасности данных, мол - "А если кто-то взломает сайт и изменит стоимость?". В связи с этим возникла потребность в двухфакторной аутентификации. Может быть вы сталкивались с подобным? Встречали ли вы примеры данной реализации в интернете? И вообще, стоит ли зацикливаться на этом моменте? Или методов защиты "из коробки" Laravel вполне достаточно?

Comment: Пример с [twilo](https://www.twilio.com/blog/2015/01/mobile-passwordless-sms-authentication-part-1-building-the-api-with-laravel-and-twilio.html) но думаю он не сильно будет отличаться от любого другого

Comment: Вы когда нибудь использовали twilo? Если потребуется подтвердить действие пользователя (например, добавление определенных данных), можно ли реализовать это через twilo?

Comment: Как вы сделаете так и будет. Твилио - это просто сервис отправки СМС.

Comment: И только? Программа для рассылки смс у нас есть, вопрос в реализации верификации на Laravel.

Comment: Да вам нужно просто сделать свой провайдер, и все, не важно через что вы его сделаете, Твило как пример, почитайте как сделать свой класс для [нотификаций](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/notifications#sms-notifications), можете прям открыть их код и переделать под себя у себе в App/Notifications

Comment: Кстати, наткнулся [laravel-twofactor-authentication](https://github.com/srmklive/laravel-twofactor-authentication)

Comment: Большое спасибо! laravel-twofactor-authentication - дошел до шага Usage, и что-то не могу понять куда добавлять код Registering User, Send token via SMS, Send token via phone call, Validating two-factor token, Deleting User. Может быть вы подскажите?